# Get Country Name from browser request using BING Maps

Tags: javascript, request, sharepoint-2013, bing-maps, web-parts

I am creating a sharepoint webpart where by i have to get the info around the country from which the request has originated. I have tried using the user agent properties as below but they do not give the right info around what was the country from which this request originated. All of the below give ""en-US" but the request originated form India.

```
navigator.browserLanguage
navigator.systemLanguage
navigator.userLanguage
navigator.language
```

I know there are free apis like http://ip-api.com/ and http://ipinfo.io but I would rather use BING maps api to get this info.

Can you please provide pointers as to how can this be achieved. Please note that I shall only have have access to the request object and from there I have to get this info.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps API allows using user's IP address to localize the search query. But it currently does not provide IP geocoding API.

If you really have to use Bing Maps' API, you can consider using [geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) to obtain the coordinates of the user then pass the coordinate to [Bing Maps' Geoencoding REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff701710.aspx). This maybe not what you need because this relies on user's privacy settings on his browser.